# Installing a new registry value under an existing key

Tags: registry, windows-installer, installshield

We have an issue where an InstallShield .MSI is not creating a registry value when upgrading from a legacy version of software. The legacy software created a key `HKLM\\Software\Company\Appname` with a few values. In the modern software, we want to add a new value `Path` to that same key (but retain the legacy values). It seems that if the key itself already exists, the installer makes no effort to create the new value. The only options exposed in InstallShield surround "create key if it doesn't exist" along with different options for uninstall behavior. There seems to be no way to say "create this value even if the key already exists".

Does anybody know a way to create a registry value entry even if the key already exists? I don't mind an InstallScript solution, except I want an uninstall to remove it.

Comment: Just set the value.  That will create the value if it doesn't yet exist.

Comment: @HansPassant It's not, though. It creates it if the key doesn't exist at all while installing, but if the key exists, no registry value is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, an interesting thing was actually happening. From the MSI logging, we determined that it was doing a `WriteRegistryValues` action near the middle of the installation, and then doing a `RemoveRegistryValues` near the end. As it turned out, this was because the `RemoveExistingProducts` action was near the end, right before the install finalization. Instead, I moved that action to near the top, between `InstallValidate` and `InstallInitialize` actions. This did the legacy uninstallation first, and then installed the correct registry settings later. I'm guessing the legacy uninstaller requested to delete the entire key.

For others that come across this issue, this solution has some drawbacks. It means that anything declared as an old product code will be removed, which may result in overwriting some settings and re-writing the files. But, for us, this drawback is better than the alternative of the registry not existing in the correct state.

My apologies for opening a question before reviewing logs, but I'm hoping someone else may benefit from this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need create separated component for new registry value, and then all should be ok.
Likely you tried to add registry key (in InstallShield) to current registry component, but when installer updates it, sees that this component already installed and doesn't do anything with it.